# Number of Inversions Algorithm with Merge Sort

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, mergesort

I'm trying to complete an assignment of an Algorithmic course offered by UC San Diego on Coursera and I got a problem...

I used merge sort to count inversions by summing the number of elements left in left array (`a` array) to the count each time you merge an element from the array in the right (`b` array), but I don't really know why it doesn't give the correct number of inversions sometimes, and it's driving me nuts, here is the code and some test cases:

```
import sys

def get_number_of_inversions(a, left, right):
    number_of_inversions = 0
    # print(a)
    if right - left <= 1:
        return number_of_inversions
    mid = (left + right) // 2
    number_of_inversions = get_number_of_inversions(a, left, mid)
    number_of_inversions = get_number_of_inversions(a, mid, right)

    left_side = a[left:mid]
    right_side = a[mid:right]

    while len(left_side) > 0 and len(right_side) > 0:
        if left_side[0] <= right_side[0]:
            a[left] = left_side[0]
            left += 1
            left_side.remove(left_side[0])
        else:
            a[left] = right_side[0]
            left += 1
            right_side.remove(right_side[0])
            number_of_inversions += len(left_side)
    if len(left_side) == 0:
        a[left] = right_side[0]
        left += 1
    else:
        a[left] = left_side[0]
        left += 1
    return number_of_inversions


if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())
    a = list(map(int, input().split()))
    print(int(get_number_of_inversions(a, 0, len(a))))
```

Test cases:

```
6
9 8 7 3 2 1
```

This one is supposed to give 15, but it gives 12

```
6
3 1 9 3 2 1
```

This one is supposed to give 9, but it gives 8

Comment: ```number_of_inversions = get_number_of_inversions(a, left, mid)
    number_of_inversions = get_number_of_inversions(a, mid, right)```
Shouldn't it be ```+=```?

Comment: That's right, I totally forgot about it, thanks!